# Ember manual url change does not update the page

Tags: ember.js

Im in need of some help. Currently if i come into my Ember app to a url like so

```
/#/clients/some-client/claims/123
```

the page loads like it should. If I manually change the url to something simple like this

```
/#/clients/some-client/claims/456
```

It does not change the data. I have to actually make sure the page does a hard refresh to get the current data.

I am getting the Event trace in the console since i have the LOG_TRANSITIONS set in my app

```
Transitioned into 'clients.client.claims.claim.index'
```

Any idea on where i could be going wrong?

The Router

```
Nucleus.Router.map(function () {
  this.resource("clients", { path: 'clients' }, function () {
    this.resource("client", { path: ':client_id' }, function () {
      this.resource("claims", function () {
        this.resource('claim', { path: '/:claim_id/:claim_sub' }, function () {
          this.resource('lines', function () {
            this.resource('line', { path: ':line_id' }, function () {
              this.resource('flags', function () {
                this.resource('flag', { path: ':flag_id' });
              });
            });
          });
        });
      });
    });
  });
  this.route("errors", { path: '/errors/:error_id' });
});
```

My routes look like so

```
Nucleus.ClientsRoute = Nucleus.Route.extend({
  model: function (params) {
    return Nucleus.Client.find('clients');
  }
});

Nucleus.ClientRoute = Nucleus.Route.extend({
  model: function (params) {
    return Nucleus.Client.find('client', params);
  }
});

    Nucleus.ClaimsRoute = Nucleus.Route.extend({
      model: function (params) {
        var client = this.modelFor('client'),
            clientId = client.get('data.id');

        params.client_id = clientId;
        return Nucleus.Claim.find('claims', params);
      },

      goToNextClaim: function (claim) {
        this.transitionTo('claim', claim);
      }
    });

    Nucleus.ClaimRoute = Nucleus.Route.extend({
      model: function (params) {
        var client = this.modelFor('client'),
            clientId = client.get('data.id');

        params.client_id = clientId;
        return Nucleus.Claim.find('claim', params);
      }
    });

Nucleus.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

  setupController: function () {
    this.controllerFor('meta_property').set('model', Nucleus.MetaProperty.find('meta_property'));
    this.controllerFor('header').set('model', Nucleus.User.find("user"));
  }

});
```

And controllers are like so

```
Nucleus.ApplicationController = Nucleus.Controller.extend({
  needs: ['meta_property'],

  isErrorPage: false,

  currentPathDidChange: function () {
    if (this.get('currentPath') === 'errors') {
      this.set('isErrorPage', true);
    } else {
      this.set('isErrorPage', false);
    }
  }.observes('currentPath')

});

Nucleus.ClaimController = Nucleus.ObjectController.extend({});
Nucleus.ClientController = Nucleus.ObjectController.extend({});
```

Comment: how do you change the url without having to do a `hard refresh`?

Comment: So if i change the URL manually and hit enter once. I get the transition event fired. To get the page to show the new data, i have to select the url and hit enter a second time. Does that make sense?

Comment: no, it doesn't..., I did understand you where hitting enter twice...

Comment: Sorry, i'll try to be more clear if i can. I also appreciate your patience and you help on other questions.

I have a URL that i hit when i first come into my ember app

    /#/clients/AMD/claims/123/4

This loads the page correctly

If i go to the URL and manually change it to 

    /#/clients/EBMC/claims/123/4

When i hit enter it logs the transition event. The page does not change, no data is updated and there are also no calls to the API.

Comment: If i select the URL a second time and hit enter, it does a true page reload giving what i need. So im trying to understand what im doing wrong and why the initial URL change, while it fires the event, does not make an api call or change the page state.

Comment: Please show more code.

Comment: updated the original post

Comment: Did you find a solution to your question?

Comment: Your router doesn't have a `/#/clients/:client_id/claims/:claim_id` route, only a `/#/clients/:client_id/claims/:claim_id/:claim_sub`.